# React NavBar can't get rid of a point

Tags: reactjs, navbar

I have here a header "NavBar" that I try to customize. But there  always appear a white point in the upper left and I don't have a clue where it comes from.

Maybe someone can help?

[image]

```
     <NavItem>
         <NavLink as="a" href="https://example.com"><img src="/img/neb.png"/></NavLink>
    </NavItem>
...
```

Comment: Are you using list tag for `<NavItem>`? If yes make sure you apply `list-style-type: none` to the `<li>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :)

I was missing the `"list-style-type: none"` in the css file.

Thanks to @PrathameshKoshti for this hint.